# Read values of tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working with Python 3.6 in PyCharm.

In the file `site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py`,

I find after line 838

```py
    with ops.name_scope(name, "convolution", [input, filter]) as name:
        input = ops.convert_to_tensor(input, name="input")  
        input_shape = input.get_shape()
        filter = ops.convert_to_tensor(filter, name="filter")  
        filter_shape = filter.get_shape()
        op = Convolution(
            input_shape,
            filter_shape,
            padding,
            strides=strides,
            dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
            name=name,
            data_format=data_format)
        return op(input,filter)
```

I want to know the values of input, filter and the returned tensor.

I tried, according to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession to do

```py
    with ops.name_scope(name, "convolution", [input, filter]) as name:
        input = ops.convert_to_tensor(input, name="input") 
        input_shape = input.get_shape()
        filter = ops.convert_to_tensor(filter, name="filter")  
        filter_shape = filter.get_shape()
        op = Convolution(
            input_shape,
            filter_shape,
            padding,
            strides=strides,
            dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
            name=name,
            data_format=data_format)
        temp = op(input,filter)
        import tensorflow as tf
        sess = tf.Session()
        with sess.as_default():
            assert tf.get_default_session() is sess
            test = filter.eval()
        return temp
```

Then, I got the error:

```
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value conv2d_1/kernel
     [[{{node conv2d_1/kernel/read}}]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a TensorFlow session, you must run the whole model by feeding data through placeholder using a `feed_dict`, after you initialized your variables.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # initialize your trainable variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Execute a training op [OP] by feeding [TENSOR]s through [PLACEHOLDER]s
    sess.run( [OP] , feed_dict = { [Placeholder]: [TENSOR] })

    # At the right point, evaluate the value of your filter object
    test = filter.eval( feed_dict = { [...] } )
```

The value of `filter` will be, at that point, stored into a numpy object `test`.
You can then return it.

I know my answer is vague, but I don't have enough information on the data in your possession. You can find a way on how to run TensorFlow's sessions [here](https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow_Tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow_2_Classification_MiniBatchGD.ipynb). Check the use of `.eval` at the end of the `tf.Session()`.

Hope this helps, otherwise let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I should have mentioned better my question was meant for during evaluation time, not training time. If I use the global_variables_initializer then, my trained weights are gone.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. In that case, can you drop the `global_variables_initializer` and `.eval` your object with a `feed_dict` ?

Comment: When I try import tensorflow as tf
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        test = filter.eval(feed_dict), I got the error that feed_dict is not defined, when I try instead feed_dict={[Placeholder]:[TENSOR]}, he says Placeholder is not defined. Should I import something?

Comment: Did you create a placeholder at the beginning to feed the data into your model?

Comment: No, should I do that in my main file or in the official tensorflow file? Is the declaration of the placeholder just like here: https://databricks.com/tensorflow/placeholders ?